# Zero Comparator with Hysteresis NOT working?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I tried to make a zero comparator with hysteresis but apparently it does not work. Any suggestions? My conditions of making the output to zero is the Hysteresis voltage level at 50mV to 2V.

See the picture for more details.

[image]

Comment: Hysteresis is positive feedback, not negative.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but your pin 8 is unconnected,

Comment: DKNguyen thanks.

Comment: A simple example circuit: https://tinyurl.com/y86yfolb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other comments, you need power connections for the simulation to work and your negative feedback does not induce hysteresis.

It's also not a great idea to use an op-amp as a comparator except in special circumstances where you have a full understanding of the situation. For one thing, the op-amp internal compensation can make the output response very slow (much slower than you would expect from the GBW and slew rate numbers because it is driven into saturation). I'm also not sure why you would use a zero-drift amplifier in such a relatively crude application.

But anyway--- here is a similar op-amp used as a comparator to illustrate one possible circuit:

[image]

Hysteresis varies from about +/-25mV to about +/-1V depending on the pot position. By shunting the pot with a fixed resistor, most of the effect of the crummy 20% pot element tolerance (and, often, bad tempco) is erased. You can play with the resistor values to get other amounts of hysteresis or to optimize the range and limits of setting.